# sum of multiple columns based on year condition

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am try to add up columns to get sum of sales made over years

[image]

how to achieve this dynamically without adding manually like

```
F.sum(2015,2016...)
```

Answer (score 0):

`SUM()` is an aggregation function, it works column-wise not row-wise. To add results across rows simply use `+` e.g.

```
(`2015`+`2016`+...)
```

Having said all of that if your objective is to support the operation in a dynamic way. I suggest normalising your data (columns to rows) so the year becomes a single column with values of 2015,2016,... Doing so will allow you employ the `SUM()` function on the year column.

Working with denormalised data is generally bad practice for all sorts of reasons and only usually employed in the final output for display/presentation purposes. i.e. poor support for changing data (such as a new year value being added).

You can normalise the data using the `STACK()` function